# Editing MediaWiki:Common.css results in Internal Error

Tags: mediawiki

I installed a MediaWiki instance on my domain and am trying to edit the MediaWiki:Common.css page, but keep getting an internal error message.  Editing regular pages works fine.

I am on MediaWiki 1.3.6 and right now have the site locked down to only registered users with:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
```

I have tried adding (I am the admin):

```
$wgGroupPermissions['administrator']['editinterface'] = true;
```

and:

```
$wgAllowUserCss = true;
```

but neither has worked.

Other suggestions welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug on how you can retrieve error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through process of elimination, it turns out my version of MediaWiki didn't like these lines in the Wikipedia Common.css:

```
1052  /* Prevent floating boxes from overlapping any category listings,
1053  file histories, edit previews, and edit [Show changes] views. */
```

Other multi-line comments had the comment indicators /* */ on each line.  I updated the lines above to do the same and it worked.  I was able to load them on my side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wgGroupPermissions['administrator']['editsitecss'] = true;
```

this should be working.